# How to get autoincrement values for a column after uploading a Pandas dataframe to a MySQL database

Tags: python, mysql, pandas, sqlalchemy

I have a Pandas DataFrame (called `df`), which I would like to upload to a MySql database. 
The dataframe has columns [*A*, *B*, *C*] and the table in the database has columns [*ID*, *A*, *B*, *C*]. The *ID* column in the database is the auto-incrementing primary key.

I can upload the dataframe to the database using the `df.to_sql('table_name', engine)` command. However, this does not give me any information about the values that the database assigned to the *ID* column of the incoming data. The only way I have of getting this information is by querying the database using the values for columns *A*, *B*, *C*:

```
select 
ID, A, B, C 
from db_table 
where (A, B, C) in ((x1, y1, z1), (x2, y2, z2), ...)
```

However, this query takes a very long time when I am inserting a lot of data.

Is there a simpler and quicker way of getting the values that the database assigned to the *ID* column of the incoming data?

**Edit 1:**
I can assign the *ID* column myself, as per user3364098's answer below. However, my job is part of a pipeline that is ran in parallel. If I assign the *ID* column myself, there is a chance that I may assign the same *id* values to different dataframes that are uploaded at the same time. This is why I would like to relegate the *ID* assignment task to the database.

**Solution:**
I ended up assigning the *ID* column myself, and issuing a lock on the table while uploading the data in order to guarantee that no other process uploads data with the same id value. Basically:

```
try:
    engine.execute('lock tables `table_name` write')
    max_id_query = 'select max(ID) FROM `table_name`'
    max_id = int(pd.read_sql_query(max_id_query, engine).values)
    df['ID'] = range(max_id + 1, max_id + len(df) + 1)
    df.to_sql('table_name', engine, if_exists='append', index=False)
finally:
    engine.execute('unlock tables')
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can assign id by yourself:

```
import pandas as pd
df['ID'] = pd.read_sql_query('select ifnull(max(id),0)+1 from db_table',cnx).iloc[0,0]+range(len(df))
```

where cnx is your connection and then upload your df.

Comment: If your database is SQL Server, use isnull instead of ifnull https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_isnull.asp

Comment: If the 'ID' is not a column you want to insert, you can assign the right half of the above answer to a variable and then assign it to a pandas column. I did on postgres: ids = pd.read_sql_query('select COALESCE(max(id),0)+1 from poi', conn).iloc[0,0]+range(len(pois)) #  pois['id'] = ids

Comment: for postgresql: pd.read_sql_query('select COALESCE(max(id), 0)+1 as max_id from table_name'  , dbConnection)

Answer (score -1):

```
import pandas as pd
df['ID'] = pd.read_sql_query('select MAX(ID)+1 from db_table',cnx).iloc[0,0] + range(len(df))
```

Comment: Could you explain what your code does, and why it is the solution to OP's problem?