# Obtain list of IDs inserted from pandas to_sql function

Tags: python, sql-server, pandas, sqlalchemy

The following Python code successfully appends the rows belonging to the pandas dataframe into an MS SQL table via the SqlAlchemy engine previously configured.

`df.to_sql(schema='stg', name = 'TEST', con=engine, if_exists='append', index=False)`

I want to obtain the auto-generated IDs numbers for each of the rows inserted into the `stg.Test` table. In other words, what is the SqlAlchemy equivalent to the [Sql Server OUTPUT clause during an INSERT statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/output-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no easy solution to your problem like an additional parameter in your statement. You have to use the behavior that new rows get the highest id + 1 assigned. With this knowledge, you can calculate the ids of all your rows.

**Option 1:** Explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26780306/7947994). You select the current maximum id, before the insert statement. Then, you assign ids to all the entries in your `DataFrame` greater than the previous maximum. Lastly, insert the df which already includes the ids.

**Option 2:** You insert the `DataFrame` and then acquire the highest id. With the number of entries inserted you can calculate the id of all entries. This is how such an insert function could look like:

```
def insert_df_and_return_ids(df, engine):
    # It is important to use same connection for both statements if
    # something like last_insert_rowid() is used
    conn = engine.connect()
    
    # Insert the df into the database
    df.to_sql('students', conn, if_exists='append', index=False)
    
    # Aquire the maximum id
    result = conn.execute('SELECT max(id) FROM students') # Should work for all SQL variants
    # result = conn.execute('Select last_insert_rowid()') # Specifically for SQLite
    # result = conn.execute('Select last_insert_id()') # Specifically for MySql


    entries = df.shape[0]
    last_id = -1
    
    # Iterate over result to get last inserted id
    for row in result:
        last_id = int(str(row[0]))
    conn.close()
    
    # Generate list of ids
    list_of_ids = list(range(last_id - entries + 1, last_id + 1))

    return list_of_ids
```

PS: I could not test the function on an MS SQL server, but the behavior should be the same. In order to test if everything behaves as it should you can use this:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import sqlalchemy as sa

# Change connection to MS SQL server
engine = sa.create_engine('sqlite:///test.lite', echo=False)

# Create table
meta = sa.MetaData()
students = sa.Table(
   'students', meta, 
   sa.Column('id', sa.Integer, primary_key = True), 
   sa.Column('name', sa.String), 
)
meta.create_all(engine)

# DataFrame to insert with two entries
df = pd.DataFrame({'name': ['Alice', 'Bob']})

ids = insert_df_and_return_ids(df, engine)
print(ids) # [1,2]

conn = engine.connect()
# Insert any entry with a high id in order to check if new ids are always the maximum
result = conn.execute("Insert into students (id, name) VALUES (53, 'Charlie')")
conn.close()

# Insert data frame again
ids = insert_df_and_return_ids(df, engine)
print(ids) # [54, 55]
```

**EDIT:** If multiple threads are utilized, transactions can be used to make the option thread-safe at least for SQLite:

```
conn = engine.connect()
transaction = conn.begin()
df.to_sql('students', conn, if_exists='append', index=False)
result = conn.execute('SELECT max(id) FROM students')
transaction.commit()
```

Comment: These options do not protect from simultaneous inserts from another database connection, i.e. another user inserting rows whilst our Python code runs. You are absolutely correct, there does not seem to exist an easy solution to this, currently, I am looking into an MS SQL-based solution that utilises the OUTPUT clause and returns the appropriate IDs, perhaps using a procedure. I'll see how it goes. Feel free to share if you get another good idea.

Comment: You are right concurrency is a problem with both options. There is the possibility to use transactions preventing any race conditions. 
If my solutions do not help you, I assume your best bet is to build your own insert SQL statement, copy the dataframe values into the statement and then use `connection.execute(statement)` as it returns the result of the query.